# How to access uncommon properties from two different object arrays that are combined into one?

Tags: typescript

Consider these object Arrays in TypeScript.

```
const objArr1: { commonProperty: string; ABC: string }[] = [
    {
        commonProperty: "I am common",
        ABC: "I am different in object 1",
    },
    {
        commonProperty: "I am common",
        ABC: "I am different in object 1",
    },
]

const objArr2: { commonProperty: string; XYZ: string }[] = [
    {
        commonProperty: "I am common",
        XYZ: "I am different in object 2",
    },
    {
        commonProperty: "I am common",
        XYZ: "I am different in object 2",
    },
]
```

I am trying to access the "un-common" properties in the combined array, like so,

```
[...objArr1, ...objArr2].forEach(obj => {
    obj.commonProperty // No error
    obj.ABC // TypeScript gets mad
    obj.XYZ // TypeScript gets mad again
})
```

But it's not letting me because `XYZ` doesn't exist on `objArr1`'s elements, and `ABC` on `objArr2`'s elements.
Can anyone suggest a workaround for this, without using type assertions or `any` keyword?

Comment: This is the exact situation that type guards are made for. You can learn about them [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
if ('ABC' in obj) obj.ABC
if ('XYZ' in obj) obj.XYZ
```